# Django celery periodic task interval change is not updating in database

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I'm using **Django 2.2** and Celery's periodic task to create a cron job which was earlier set to run at an interval of 2 hours like

```
@periodic_task(name='authentication.periodic_task.custom', run_every=timedelta(hours=2))
```

Now, I changed it to run every day at 2 PM instead of running every two hours and updated schedule is

```
@periodic_task(
    name='authentication.periodic_task.custom',
    run_every=crontab(hour=2, minute=0)
)
```

Replace `timedelta` with `crontab` but the task is still executing every 2 hours.

When I checked the Django admin, it has a listing in `Periodic Tasks` table with the following data

[image]

**Why the change in the period in the code is not updated in the database?**

The celery is configured to run via supervisor

```
# Run app
celery -A app worker -l info

# Run celery beat
celery -A app beat -l debug
```

Comment: what scheduler class do you use

Answer (score 0):

The more likely cause is incorrect run.

Celery worker is just running a periodic tasks, but it's running only a tasks that already inside async queue. For provide this you can run embed celery beat:

```
celery -A proj worker -B
```

This is convenient if you’ll never run more than one worker node but it’s not commonly used and for that reason isn’t recommended for production use.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the celery run command. Using the same command from the supervisor. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you seem to be using Database-backed Periodic Tasks you should edit your task execution rules in database as in [example](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#example-creating-crontab-based-periodic-task).

---

This type of celery-beat backend does not use task decorators to set beat rules but instead database models should be created as documented, you can also add or edit tasks execution rules from Django Admin